# Custom Taxonomy page redirecting to 404 page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I am using `CPT UI` plugin for creating `custom post types` and `custom taxonomies`

I created a `custom taxonomy` named `hotel` and assigned that to `custom post type` called `hotel` as well and the taxonomy is hierarchical. Then I list those taxonomies in Hotels page and that is fine.

But when I create taxonomy page (`taxonomy-hotel.php`) the page redirection(`permalink`) from Hotels page(`page-hotels.php`) goes to 404 error page. And my taxonomy page(`taxonomy-hotel.php`) is not getting.

Am I did anything wrong ? If so, where is the error. And how can I fix this issue ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: did try flushing Permalinks from `Settings > Permalinks` Page

Comment: @Kudratullah You mean by changing the Settings of Permalinks ? If so, I did it as well.